# Django Loop for Window expand/collapse without JQuery

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I'm working using Django. I'm new to coding and working on my first project. I do not know JQuery, but I read that it's possible to collapse/expand a window without JQuery.

I followed this webpage: [CSS Expand/Collapse Section (A PEN BY Peter Nguyen)](https://codepen.io/peternguyen/pen/hICga/)

The problem is that I'm trying to use this in a for loop. I'm able to get the layout how I want it, but when I use expand/collapse it only works for the first item in the loop. So, expand/collapse works perfectly on the first iteration of the loop, but not the rest.

HTML

```
    {% for assignment in assignments %}
    <form id=form action= "/project/assignments" method='post'>
      {% csrf_token %} 
        <label class=labels><a href="{% url 'project:assg' assignment_id=assignment.id %}">
          Assignment: {{assignment.denominator}} - {{assignment.description}} </a></label>
        <input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle" id=labels2>Criteria</label>
        <div id=expand>
          <section>
            <p>[Number] [Name]: Expand content goes here.
            </p>
          </section>
        </div>
        <section>
        <textarea id=boxes name="review">{{assignments.review}}</textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="Function_id" value={{assignments.id}}>
        <input class=save_tasks type="submit" value="Save">
        </section>
    </form>
```

CSS

```
#toggle{
display: none;
visibility:hidden;
}
#labels2{
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 4px solid #5e6b39;
    border-left: 4px solid #5e6b39;
    border-right: 4px solid #5e6b39; 
    width: 881px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: -6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#labels2:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#labels2::before {
    font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    content: "+";
    vertical-align: text-top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #CCC 50%, transparent 
    50%);
    }

#expand {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #5e6b39;
    border-left: 4px solid #5e6b39;
    border-right: 4px solid #5e6b39;
    width: 881px;
    padding: 10px;
    /* margin-top: -30px; */
  }

#toggle:checked ~ #expand {
    height: 180px;
}

#toggle:checked ~ #labels2::before {
    content: "-";
}
```

How do I get the collapse/expand division to expand/collapse for all the items in the loop and not just the first one? Is my Django loop incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is not the problem here.

You only use IDs in your code, and since they are supposed to be unique on a page, the browser uses only the first element that can be found.

> The id global attribute defines a **unique** identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).
>
> *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id*

---

I have adjusted your code once in the necessary places:

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.labels2 {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 4px solid #5e6b39;
  border-left: 4px solid #5e6b39;
  border-right: 4px solid #5e6b39; 
  width: 881px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.labels2:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.labels2::before {
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  content: "+";
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.expand {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #5e6b39;
  border-left: 4px solid #5e6b39;
  border-right: 4px solid #5e6b39;
  width: 881px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* margin-top: -30px; */
}

.toggle:checked ~ .expand {
  height: 180px;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .labels2::before {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
{% for assignment in assignments %}
  <form id=form action= "/project/assignments" method='post'>

    {% csrf_token %} 

      <label class=labels><a href="{% url 'project:assg' assignment_id=assignment.id %}">Assignment: {{assignment.denominator}} - {{assignment.description}}</a></label>

      <input id="toggle-{{assignments.id}}" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
      <label for="toggle-{{assignments.id}}" class="labels2">Criteria</label>

      <div class="expand">
        <section>
          <p>[Number] [Name]: Expand content goes here.</p>
        </section>
      </div>

      <section>
        <textarea id=boxes name="review">{{assignments.review}}</textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="Function_id" value={{assignments.id}}>
        <input class=save_tasks type="submit" value="Save">
      </section>

  </form>
```

---

At this point it is important that the input `class="toggle"` and the label `class="labels2"` get a unique distinction in the `id` and the `for` attribute, so that the click on the label also checks the correct input.

For this you should work with a dynamic value like `toggle-{{assignments.id}}` - *Which I would also highly recommend in principle for all IDs in a loop*.

---

I hope that could help :)

Comment: Perfect - That's how it should be :)